# getting nullPointerException on simple game

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, 2d, render

I am making a simple rpg game and i have been trying to add enemies to the game. It is loading in the enemy find with all it's stats, but when i try to render it, i get `Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.hosfordryan.tileRPG.entities.Enemy.render(Enemy.java:52)
    at com.hosfordryan.tileRPG.Game.render(Game.java:134)
    at com.hosfordryan.tileRPG.Game.run(Game.java:103)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`
. I have used JOptionPanes to confirm that the enemies are saving in the arrayList, so that can't be it. Code for reading in enemy is:

```
public static void loadEnemies() {
    Scanner qwe;
    try {
        qwe = new Scanner(new File("enemyStats.txt"));
        while (qwe.hasNextLine()) {
            String name = qwe.nextLine();
            String origin = qwe.nextLine();
            String weapon = qwe.nextLine();
            String gear = qwe.nextLine();
            String spec = qwe.nextLine();
            int hp = qwe.nextInt();
            int att = qwe.nextInt();
            int def = qwe.nextInt();
            int randX = (int) (Math.random()*(20*SCALE*TILESIZE));  //Give random x coordinate
            int randY = (int) (Math.random()*(20*SCALE*TILESIZE));  //Give random y coordinate
            if(qwe.hasNextLine()){
                qwe.nextLine();
            }
            enemies.add(new Enemy(randX,randY,im,name,origin,weapon,gear,spec,hp,att,def));     //adds enemy into arrayList
            String temp = "";
            temp+=enemies.get(enemies.size()-1).getName()+"\n"+enemies.get(enemies.size()-1).getRx();   //checking if saving into arrayList correctly
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, temp);


        }

        for(int i = 0; i < enemies.size();i++){     //adds enemy to arrayList to be rendered
            enemiestoRend.add( new Enemy(enemies.get(i).getRx(),enemies.get(i).getRy(),im,enemies.get(i).getName(),enemies.get(i).getOrigin(),enemies.get(i).getWeapon(),enemies.get(i).getGear(),enemies.get(i).getSpecialMove(),enemies.get(i).gethp()
                    ,enemies.get(i).getAttack(),enemies.get(i).getDefense()));
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Code for rendering:

```
public void render(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(im.enemy, this.x*Game.TILESIZE * Game.SCALE, this.x*Game.TILESIZE * Game.SCALE, Game.TILESIZE * Game.SCALE,
            Game.TILESIZE * Game.SCALE, null);
}
```

Render method in main which renders everything:

```
public void render(){
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs==null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics g= bs.getDrawGraphics();
    //Render Here

    else if(Player.l1){
        l1.render(g);

    }
    for(int i = 0; i < enemies.size();i++){
        enemies.get(i).render(g);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < enemiestoRend.size();i++){
        enemiestoRend.get(i).render(g);             //problem here
    }

    player.render(g);
    //End Render
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
```

Comment: What is the "im" variable?  That seems like the best candidate for being null and causing the exception.

Comment: `this.x` is also a good candidate if you are using boxing/unboxing e. g. `this.x` being `Integer` instead of `int`

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: the im variable is `im = new ImageManager(ss);` which is what is responsible for cutting up my spritesheet